# Number of solutions of $N_9 + N_8 + N_7 + N_6 + N_5 + N_4 + N_3 + N_2 + N_1 = 82$ in the positive odd integers with $N_i \leq N_{i - 1}$

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Given $N_{tot}=82$ where $N = [N_9 \: N_8 \:N_7 \:N_6 \:N_5 \:N_4 \:N_3 \:N_2 \:N_1 \:N_0]$, how many possible combinations are there if each $N_i$ must be odd and $N_i \leq N_{i-1}$, i.e. one solution is $[1 \:1 \:1 \:3 \:3 \:5 \:7 \:13 \:19 \:29]$.

If $N_i$ can be any positive integer I have worked down the solution to ${81 \choose 9}$ which I think is correct not sure how to work it when $N_i$ can only be odd. Sorry don't know a lot about combinations!

Comment: hint: order doesnt count which means not a permutation

Comment: If $N_i\lt N_{i-1}$ then $[1\,1\,1\,3\cdots]$ is not a solution. Did you mean $N_i\le N_{i-1}$?

Comment: Yes should be Ni≤Ni−1

Comment: @user2887210 u can edit the question preferably with ur own attempt for solving it

Comment: @user2887210  To clarify, are you seeking the number of solutions in odd positive integers to the equation $$N_9 + N_8 + N_7 + N_6 + N_5 + N_4 + N_3 + N_2 + N_1 + N_0 = 82$$ in which $N_i \leq N_{i - 1}$ for $1 \leq i \leq 9$?

Comment: @N. F. Taussig Yes that is correct

Comment: @user2887210  In that case, shouldn't your question say $N_i$ must be odd rather than $N$ must be odd?  Please edit your question to clarify exactly what you mean.

Comment: Your $81 \choose 9$ is correct without the restriction of odd $N_i$ and without the restriction of the $N_i$ being ordered.  If you remove the restriction of ordering, you can take one off each of the $N_i$ to make them even, then divide by $2$, and you want weak compositions of $36$ into $10$ pieces.  There are $45 \choose 9$ of those.

Comment: @RossMillikan u forgot repetition, and negliged permutations

Comment: @Idle001:  No, I didn't. It is a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) argument.  I got rid of the restriction that the $N_i$ be odd, then added $1$ so they are all positive, then split the $46$ items into $10$ pieces. As I said, that does not guarantee that the $N_i$ are increasing, but neither does OP's $81 /choose 9$, which is achieved the same way as my argument.

Comment: @RossMillikan hmmmm i missed that, since N must be odd , combinations are taken from 41 values !

Comment: @Idle001 Thanks for all help so far. I have been told that there are in fact 9418 distinct combinations. However I do not know how to arrive at that answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **Notice:** This calculation is approximating the sum to lower bound because number of permutations of tuples containing redundancy like $xxyy$ or $xyyy$ is not 4! but less.

One attempt is divide and conqueer, first enumerate cases of :

{1,1,1...(N-1)...1,(82-(N-1))/2},{1,1,1...(N-2)...3,(82-(N-1)-2)/2} which leads to

$P_2=\binom{\frac{\lfloor 82-(N-1)\rfloor}{2}}1$

Since permutations arent allowed (one unique order)

$C_2=\frac{\binom{\frac{\lfloor 82-(N-1)\rfloor}{2}}1}{2!}$

The combination of (k-1) elements are taken from one set, so that the remaining number is constraintly summing up to 82

Following this approach.

$C_3=\frac{\binom{\frac{\lfloor 82-(N-1)-2\rfloor}{2}}2}{3!}$

....

$C_{N}=\frac{\binom{\frac{\lfloor 82-(N-1)-(N-1)\rfloor}{2}}{N-1}}{{N}!}=$
$\frac{\binom{\frac{\lfloor 82-2N+2\rfloor}{2}}{N-1}}{{N}!}$

The overall is the sum of all $C$s, hope I havent miss anything.

Comment: Thanks for all help so far. I have been told that there are in fact 9418 distinct combinations. However I do not know how to arrive at that answer.